# returning <class 'list'> instead of an object in sqlalcheny

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have my test model :

```
from shop import db
    
    
class Product(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
  price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
  description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

I create the db, add product, commit :

```
db.create_all()
from shop.models import Product
p1 = Product(name='p1', price=120.55, description='<h1>tag</h1>')
db.session.add(p1)
db.session.commit()
```

but when I query the data I get this:

```
Product.query.all()
>>> [<Product 1>]
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: I wanna have an object not a <class 'list'>

Comment: I ve seen tutorial where they put the same query and they get a list (Array) of products

Comment: no brother .. I don't get a list that I can work with

Comment: The square brackets you see are Python's way of printing a list, the item inside it is printed however the object wants to be printed via its `__str__` method (in this case it prints the object type and ID). What you have is a list containing one object.

Comment: If you only want one "thing" then perhaps try `.one()` instead of `.all()`